# What is Initialize in Entity Framework Core?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

```
public ExampleDbContext()
{
    Initialize.EncryptionKey = "example_encrypt_key";
    this._provider = new GenerateEncryptionProvider();
}
```

I came across the abovw sample code of EntityFrameworkCore.EncryptColumn in github, but when I copied these two lines of codes to my

```
public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options) : base(options)
{
}
```

I get the error saying the name 'Initialize' does not exist in the current context. I can't find where the Initialize come from, is it I should change it to something else?

Comment: `I came across the abovw sample code of EntityFrameworkCore.EncryptColumn in github` - please share the URL

Comment: believe I found it, have a look at the readme.md of the project - https://github.com/emrekizildas/EntityFrameworkCore.EncryptColumn - it does say under `How to use?` `Install "EntityFrameworkCore.EncryptColumn" package to your project.` did  you install the mentioned package?

Comment: as stated in the github doc, u must install this nuget "EntityFrameworkCore.EncryptColumn'

Comment: Yes, thats the repository I am saying. I installed EntityFrameworkCore.EncryptColumn, its not warning me about missing that I guess?